# How to get the default selected value of dropdown on ngOnInit using Reactive form in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a select dropdown list. An option is selected by default when the page loads. I would like to get the default value during `ngOnInit()`. However, its returning empty value.

**HTML**

```
<select (change)="segmentOneSelected()" formControlName="segmentOne" class="form-control segment-1">
  <option [attr.value]="-1">Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let segment of segmentsForAnalysis" [attr.value]="segment.index" [attr.selected]="segment.name == 2 ? true : null">{{segment.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**Component**

```
get segmentOne() { return this.myForm.get('segmentOne'); }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.segmentOne.value);
  // returns empty string ""
}
```

Comment: Where else is anotherSegment.name?

Comment: `anotherSegment.name` is an object that I'm passing but you can ignore that. Maybe just consider it as a static value eg. 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reactive form this is typically done in the typescript part of the code

```
  segmentForm: FormGroup;
  segmentsForAnalysis = [
    {name: 'one', value: 1},
    {name: 'two', value: 2},
    {name: 'three', value: 3}];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit()
  {

    this.segmentForm = new FormGroup({
      'segmentOne': new FormControl(this.segmentsForAnalysis[0].value) //<---
    });

  }
```

Then in html part

```
<form [formGroup]="segmentForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <select (change)="segmentOneSelected()" formControlName="segmentOne" class="form-control segment-1">
    <option *ngFor="let segment of segmentsForAnalysis" [value]="segment.value" >{{segment.name}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

selected attribute doesn't work in Angular.

If you want to give your select a value, you do it when you instantiate your form :

```
segmentsForAnalysis = [
  { index: 0, name: 'Segment 1' },
  { index: 1, name: 'Segment 2' },
]

this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  segmentOne: [this.segmentsForAnalysis[1].name, [/* Validators */]]
})
```

Comment: `selected` attribute does seems to partially working for me. Its selecting the dropdown correctly from the list. However, it not returning the value until I manually reselect the dropdown from the list.

Comment: First time that I see it working for someone ! Well anyways, my response should resolve your issue :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have a value pre-selected in your combo box, you need to set the value in your form control. For e.g. you have defined your form group as:

```
private segmentFormGroup: FormGroup;
```

In your ngOnInit(), you initialize your form group as:

```
this.segmentFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  segmentOne: ['pre-selected-value', [Validators.required]]
});
```

Thus you set the pre-selected value to 'pre-selected-value'. Note, however, that your option list has to have the value 'pre-selected-value'.

Alternatively, if you need to dynamically set the pre-selected value in ngOnInit() based on some logic, you can use the patchValue() method of formGroup to set value as shown below:

```
this.segmentFormGroup.patchValue({
  'segmentOne': 'pre-selected-value'
});
```

Finally, if you want to retrieve the selected value, you can use the following snippet:

```
let selectedValue = this.segmentFormGroup.get('segmentOne').value;
```